# Error with solving system of ODEs in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, ode

I'm trying to solve the following Toda system of ODE in MATLAB:

a_k' = 2*(b_k^2 - b_(k-1)^2) for k = 1,...,m with b_0 = b_m = 0

b_k' = b_k*(a_(k+1) - a_k) for k = 1,...,m-1

with arbitrary initial conditions (non-zero for b). I've tried the following code:

```
syms t
syms a_1(t) a_2(t) a_3(t) a_4(t) a_5(t) a_6(t) a_7(t) a_8(t) a_9(t) a_10(t)
syms b_1(t) b_2(t) b_3(t) b_4(t) b_5(t) b_6(t) b_7(t) b_8(t) b_9(t)

a_1_10 = [a_1; a_2; a_3; a_4; a_5; a_6; a_7; a_8; a_9; a_10];
a_1_9 = [a_1; a_2; a_3; a_4; a_5; a_6; a_7; a_8; a_9];
a_2_10 = [a_2; a_3; a_4; a_5; a_6; a_7; a_8; a_9; a_10];

b_1_10 = [b_1; b_2; b_3; b_4; b_5; b_6; b_7; b_8; b_9; 0];
b_0_9 = [0; b_1; b_2; b_3; b_4; b_5; b_6; b_7; b_8; b_9];
b_1_9 = [b_1; b_2; b_3; b_4; b_5; b_6; b_7; b_8; b_9];

eqns_a = diff(a_1_10) == 2.*(b_1_10.^2 - b_0_9.^2);
eqns_b = diff(b_1_9) == b_1_9 .* (a_2_10 - a_1_9);
eqns = [eqns_a; eqns_b];

init_a = a_1_10(0) == randn(10,1);
init_b = b_1_9(0) == randn(9,1);
init = [init_a; init_b];

S = dsolve(eqns, init);
```

but I keep getting the error:

```
Error using mupadengine/feval (line 163)
The equations are invalid.

Error in dsolve>mupadDsolve (line 336)
T = feval(symengine,'symobj::dsolve',sys,x,options);

Error in dsolve (line 193)
sol = mupadDsolve(args, options);
```

I would also like to be able to run this code for many different different values of m (i.e. vectors of functions larger or smaller than 10), but I don't mind doing it somewhat manually if necessary.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you expect analytic solutions?

Comment: I think I am supposed to.

Comment: `a_1_10(0)` is not valid Matlab syntax, Matlab indexing starts at 1, not 0. That might be the issue.